# Статус коды для поисковых роботов на клиенте

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

Есть приложение написаное на react + react-router.

Как возвращаться статусы ошибок роботу, с клиентского прилоения ? То есть робот приходит на сайт ему возвращается клиентское приложение со статусов 200(какой то компонет), он идет на не существующий роут который перехватывает react-router возвращает компонент ошибки, но для робота это все ровно 200, то есть куда бы не пошел робот у него всегда статус 200 тк ошибки с сервера перехватывает react, как решить эту проблему ?

Comment: В форумах что-то пишут про soft 404 error